# Queries Facebook sdk 2.1 for unity3d

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, location

I am developing an application on Unity and need location information of my friends. Facebook Graph API says i have to submit the app for review before accessing these informations. Since my target platform is not facebook but iOS and Android. Why do i need to submit the app here?

Facebook also asks for apk build and iOS link, Do they review this like iTunes? Please clarify.

If yes, How can i submit the build when its still in development phase ?

Any suggestions would really be helpful.

Thanks in advance...